# Counting employees in country - user input not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing query that returns number of people working in country. User have to input COUNTRY_ID which he is interested in.

I wrote down query that works fine, but only with hardcoded  COUNTRY_ID.

```
SELECT COUNT(e.EMPLOYEE_ID)
FROM EMPLOYEES e
JOIN DEPARTMENTS d ON e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
JOIN LOCATIONS l ON d.LOCATION_ID = l.LOCATION_ID
JOIN COUNTRIES c ON l.COUNTRY_ID = c.COUNTRY_ID
WHERE c.COUNTRY_ID = 'US';
```

With hardcoded COUNTRY_ID query returns 68 rows, with user input query returns 0 rows.

```
c.COUNTRY_ID = '&c.COUNTRY_ID'
```

Maybe I'm using this function wrongly, I would be glad for solution. Thanks.

Comment: User input from where? What is your calling code written in, pl/sql, java,...?

Comment: When I said user input i ment this line with ampersand 
When i replace c.country_id = 'US' with   '&c.COUNTRY_ID' it doesn't work

Comment: SQL*Plus? Try if it works, when you remove the `c.` for the substitution variable's name, so that you get `c.COUNTRY_ID = '&COUNTRY_ID'`.

Comment: It worked out, thanks a lot. Btw maybe you know why it didn't work?